# Como usar template em diretivas com restrict M (comentários)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou tentando usar a opção `restrict` com o valor `'M'` (para o angular trabalhar através de comentários) para criar uma diretiva. Porém o comentário não está incorporando o valor que eu estou adicionando em `template`.

Veja:

```js
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('stackoverflow', function () {

    return {
         restrict: 'M',
         template: '<div>my name is wallace</div>'
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="example">
    <!-- directive: stackoverflow -->
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Se eu fizer com a `A` ou `E` (para ler atributos ou elementos, respectivamente), funciona perfeitamente:

```js
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('stackoverflow', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<div>my name is wallace</div>'
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="example">
  <div stackoverflow></div>
  <stackoverflow></stackoverflow>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Por que a diretiva com restrição `M` não funcionou no primeiro exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um comentário não pode possuir elementos-filhos. Entretanto você pode compilar o elemento resultante da avaliação do *controller* após o comentário em si:

```js
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('stackoverflow', function ($compile) {

    return {
         restrict: 'M',
         template: '<div>my name is wallace</div>',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs)
         {
             console.log(element[0].innerHTML);
             element.after($compile(element[0].innerHTML)(scope));
         }
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="example">
    <!-- directive: stackoverflow -->
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como complemento à resposta do OnoSendai, gostaria de acrescentar que ao adicionar a propriedade `replace: true`, as diretivas com restrição `M` passam a funcionar com template.

Veja:

```js
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('stackoverflow', function () {

  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'M',
    template: '<div>my name is wallace</div>'
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="example">
  <!-- directive: stackoverflow -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Funcionou muito bem.